# Could not find generator 'vkontakte_api:install' Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, generator

When I do the following:

> $ rails generate vkontakte_api:install

I get an error:

> Could not find generator 'vkontakte_api:install'

How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to generate?

Comment: it's gives a list of api settings of "vk.com" web resource